# How can I transfer tether(USDT) using omni JSON RPC API?

Tags: omni, tether

I looked for the information but I couldn't find that. It seemed to be done as I always do for Bitcoin though.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for Omni layer token you do this `omni_send`
https://github.com/OmniLayer/omnicore/blob/master/src/omnicore/doc/rpc-api.md#omni_send
This is what you need (at least on Kraken and Bittrex USDT is Omnilayer token). To send Omnilayer transaction you need to have some BTC on the same address for transaction fee. And you also need to know USDT `propertyId` which is 31 (https://omniexplorer.info/asset/31)

Just in case:

For ETH token you do `eth_sendTransaction`(different methods are possible like `eth_sendRawTransaction`) https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction. You need to know contract address of the token and it is your parameter `to`, `from` is normal address from here is the funny part - token transaction is defined in data. Lets take an example https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6fcf7dc3f6bc2b7e8a9e6b13689d042e659b2d016a3bdf7beffd033ab9b6db1e
this is 2.55 BNB(contract address 0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52,  parameter `to`) token transfer(method name encoded in `data` as first 10 digits 0xa9059cbb) from 0x0861d1b074eb2489dd7878a5d6d869db5896a5f0 (parameter `from`) to 0x4283f315788b09a357ca83b8134cd48bde8b556f (middle part of `data` with some padding 0000000000000000000000004283f315788b09a357ca83b8134cd48bde8b556f). Last part of `data` is token amount in wei. BNB has 18 decimal places and the best way to explain that IMHO is this python assertion:

`assert int('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023803234a2f38c00', 16) * 1e-18 == 2.55809979`

Answer (score 1):

USDT is **also** an ERC20 contract in Ethereum mainnet. You need to use one of Ethereum Wallet accepting RPC calls (Geth, Parity, etc.). Then find contract address (check Etherscan). Then install contract to your wallet and manage your transaction.

Comment: I saw that it was on Omni layers on their website though .

Comment: Tether is also on the omni layer (it was originally only here, ERC20 is a new addition): https://www.omniexplorer.info/address/3MbYQMMmSkC3AgWkj9FMo5LsPTW1zBTwXL

Comment: Ohh.. My bad. Ignore my answer then.